# Printing checker board in python

Tags: python

So I'm generating a random board by the following.

```
def getBoard(size)
    randomStart = []
    for i in range(0. size)
        column = [i, random.randrange(0, size)]
        randomStart.append(column)
    return randomStart
```

Then if for example I get the following board.[[0, 3],[1, 1],[2, 4],[3, 0],[4, 3]]

I'm then trying to print the board to look something like this.

```
- - - X - 
- X - - - 
- - - - X 
X - - - - 
- - - X -
```

The way I am trying to do it is have a string "line" and print row by row and if the column equals the random column position if prints an X.
I can't see to wrap my head around how to do this for some reason. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: FYI - you are missing `:` in our function definition and for loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cleaned up your code a bit. If I understood you correctly, the solution would be:

```
import random


def get_board(size):
    random_start = []
    for i in range(size):
        column = [i, random.randrange(size)]
        random_start.append(column)
    return random_start


def print_board(size):
    occupied = get_board(size)
    for i in range(size):
        for j in range(size):
            if [i, j] in occupied:
                print("X ", end='')  # end='' to prevent newlines
            else:
                print("- ", end='')
        print("")  # newline after a row
```

Answer (score 2):

Just print row by row, checking if each point is in your list of points that should be marked with an X:

```
size = 5
points = [[0, 3],[1, 1],[2, 4],[3, 0],[4, 3]]

for j in range(size):
    row = ""
    for i in range(size):
        if [i,j] in points:
            row += "X "
        else:
            row += "- "
    print(row)
```

**Output**

```
- - - X -
- X - - -
- - - - -
X - - - X
- - X - -
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `numpy` approach that outputs your board as a matrix:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)

size = 5
board = np.zeros((size, size)).astype(str)
board[board=='0.0'] = '-'

points = [[i, np.random.randint(size)] for i in range(size)]
mapping = {tuple(i): 'X' for i in points}

for i, j in mapping.keys():
    board[i,j] = mapping[(i,j)]
```

Returns:

```
[['-' '-' '-' '-' 'X']
 ['X' '-' '-' '-' '-']
 ['-' '-' '-' 'X' '-']
 ['-' '-' '-' 'X' '-']
 ['-' '-' '-' 'X' '-']]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
board = getBoard(5)
for line in board:
    print (' '.join('X' if i == line[1] else '-' for i in range(len(board))))
```

This creates a list of `-` and `X` characters and then uses `join` to concatenate it into a single string, for each line.